# I retrieved a date from my database using jQuery. The retrieved value is "2012-01-10 00:00:00" (quotes included)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was unable to perform date comparison operations because it was being retrieved as a string. How can I do that. I tried using below syntax, but it didn't work.

```
DateUtils.convertFormat(emp_date_start,"MM/dd/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: can you show us your code snippet..How you are fetching date and comparing...

Comment: @Pranav : var emp_date_start = JSON.stringify(consutlantInfo['0']['date_start']);

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify()`? Please tell us what value is in `consutlantInfo['0']['date_start']`. Your `DateUtils` library(?) might have a function to do the conversion you want, but that is not a standard (built-in) JavaScript object so you'd need to check its documentation.

Comment: @Pranav : i would perform date comparison based on the emp_date_start and another variable that already holds date. that would look something like "emp_date_start > new_date"...

Comment: @nnnnnn: i am using ajax call to fetch the results of a query and holding that data in an object called "consultantInfo". In that ['0'] corresponds to first row and ['date_start'] is the name of the column in my database.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that much. What I'm asking is what actual value ends up in `consutlantInfo['0']['date_start']`? If you do `console.log(consutlantInfo['0']['date_start'])` what do you see in your browser's console? (Whatever the value is you should be working with it or converting from it directly, you don't need to use `JSON.stringify()` on it.)

Comment: @nnnnnn : you are the man of the hour! thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Convert your String into date Format and then Compare it :-

```
 var dateCon=new Date(emp_date_start);
 //Now Compare :-
 if(dateCon > new_date)
```

Comment: What consutlantInfo['0']['date_start'] is returning to you ..a date ..??

Comment: string format shown can't be passed to `Date()` as is and OP already has a library at their disposal. Just need to read the library docs

Comment: @Pranav : JSON.stringify(emp_date_start) is returning me the date in string format. so new Date couldnt convert it into date format. without using JSON.stringify i tried retrieving the value. It worked perfectly fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() is not all required to fetch it from the database.

simply I used

```
 var new_date = consultantInfo['0']['date_start'];
```

to fetch from the ajax object that i used to retrieve from the database.